# $(document).on("click",".class_name",function() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="menu" class='rmm' data-menu-title="Description">
    <ul>
        <li><a  href=""  class="rmm_li_item">Description</a></li>
        <li><a  href="" class="rmm_li_item">Features</a></li>
        <li><a  href=""  class="rmm_li_item">Ratings</a></li>
        <li><a  href=""  class="rmm_li_item">Activate</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jquery portion to change menu title

```
function getMobileMenu() {

    /*  build toggled dropdown menu list */

    $('.rmm').each(function() { 
        var menutitle = $(this).attr("data-menu-title");
        if ( menutitle == "" ) {
            menutitle = "Menu";
        }
        else if ( menutitle == undefined ) {
            menutitle = "Menu";
        }
        var $menulist = $(this).children('.rmm-main-list').html();
        var $menucontrols ="<div class='rmm-toggled-controls'><div class='rmm-toggled-title'>" + menutitle + "</div><div class='rmm-button'><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span></div></div>";
        $(this).prepend("<div class='rmm-toggled rmm-closed'>"+$menucontrols+"<ul>"+$menulist+"</ul></div>");

    });
}
```

I just want the menu title to be changed when I click the menu.

I tried the below but it won't work

```
$(document).on("click",".rmm_li_item",function()
    var ctxt=this.innerHTML;
    $(".rmm-toggled-title").text(ctxt);
})
```

complete design : responsivemobilemenu.com/en/

Comment: please try to execute your whole code on jsfiddle.net and see what error you get

Answer (score 0):

the code may syntax error you have missed callback function stating braket `{`, try this code

```
 $(document).on("click",".rmm_li_item",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var ctxt=this.innerHTML;
     $(".rmm-toggled-title").text(ctxt);
  })
```

Although add `e.preventDefault()` to stop reloading page

Comment: check console, there any other error so this code stuck

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be some error in your on Click event.General syntax is for onClick event is

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

According to the question is this what you need?

```
$(document).on("click",".rmm_li_item",function(e){
   e.preventDefault()
   var ctxt=this.innerHTML;
   $(".rmm").text(ctxt);
  })
```

IF not please make a JSFIDDLE and share the link I could not comprehend what you said